# How is "duhduhb" written properly in Amharic?

Tags: writing

I learned the word "dub-dub" the other day meaning `moron` in Amharic.

After a couple of searches I found [this page](http://swearcentral.com/amharic/) which says:

> Duhduhb = Moron

---

I tried having a stab at how it might be written, properly, in Amharic based off of the [Alphasyllabary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic#Alphasyllabary) on Wikipedia and came up with something like: ዱዱቧ. But, it seems I'm way off base.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "uh" here is meant to represent the phoneme `/ə/`. Nobody can really agree on how to transcribe Ge'ez-script vowels, but I've most often seen it written *ä*, and this is what Wikipedia uses.

Thus, the word is [*dädäb*](http://www.amharicdictionary.com/Home/Index/%E1%8B%B3%E1%8B%B3%E1%89%A5), ደደብ.